# How to make a pile of 3-D objects like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d

I'm new to Photoshop, and I was wondering how I would be able to create something like this but with real planets. What would be my best option to create this?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What have you tried? What has failed?

Comment: I don't really know where to start, I've tried just stacking images but looks very flat

Comment: There are good tutorials on youtube for making realistic 3D planets. Try some of those.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop has a few preset 3D shapes. Sphere is one of them. To use it you you have an image layer and apply 3D > New shape from layer > Sphere

[image]

Photoshop assumes the image layer is a plane map of spherical surface and creates the spherical map:

[image]

The sphere can be rotated freely and the light conditions can be adjusted with the 3D panel tools.

The result looks quite plausible spherical earth map because the image happened to be a high resolution equirectangular plane map of the earth. Creating equirectangular plane projections of spheres has been discussed here in GDSE several times. My map was copied from Wikipedia article of equirectangular maps.

You need a bunch of different images. I guess you are not going to use earth maps, but something else. From where to get good images without painting them is out of the scope of this answer. There's also the copyright question. If you get somehow good images check carefully what is your right to use them.

If you have something else than an equirectangular plane map as your starting image the poles will be pinched and the equator will be stretched. The sphere is made anyway.

The generated shape can be rasterized and new one can be made until you have enough of them. Use low enough resolution to have a possiblilty to keep say 100 different layers.

If you expect that the spheres make shadows over each other you must either use a real 3D program or paint the shadows manually.

I guess you do not get realistic planet surface images as equirectangular planar projections easily. Some old planet map generator programs can be found from the web but I have not got them working. That can be caused by lack of knowledge how to run complex command line programs. I do not claim working ones do not exist, so try them and hopefully you have better luck.

This site https://www.nuketown.com/random-planet-generators/  has links also to online planet surface generators, which may be easier, but I have not tested them and I do not know if the generated images can be legally used.

If you do not get good equirectangular images try Plan B.

Plan B: Draw or paint an image. Use Filter > Distort > Spherize to get easily right looking spherical perspective. Learn to paint dark shading. Use layer style outer glow to create glowing gas atmosphere. You get quite easily something like this

[image]

You may need also Plan C. Forget astronomically plausible look. Invent some stories which make the presented planets look right in the framework of those stories. For example "The inhabitants of this planet have instead of making money developed higher level spiritual ambitions. The way how they have crafted the surface of their planet doesn't present short sighted rapacity, but deep respect to gods and uncompromised belief on the power of humble supplications"

[image]